# spring boot property with profile from dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Problem:**

I have 3 parts in the software:

- Client A service
- Client B service
- Target C service

I want to connect to C from A and B
I wrote a library with following setup:

- /src/main/java/pkg.../TargetConnector.java
- /src/main/java/pkg.../TargetConfig.java
- /src/main/resources/application-dev.properties
- /src/main/resources/application-tst.properties
- /src/main/resources/application-prd.properties

My clients A and B both have there own sources and properties:

- /src/main/java/pkg.../Client{A/B}Service.java
- /src/main/java/pkg.../Client{A/B}Config.java
- /src/main/resources/application-dev.properties
- /src/main/resources/application-tst.properties
- /src/main/resources/application-prd.properties

The properties of the Connector contains some login info for the service e.g.

```
target.url=https://....
target.usr=blablabla
target.key=mySHAkey
```

which is used in the TargetConfig to preconfigure the Connector e.g.

```
@Value("target.url")
String url;
@Value("target.usr")
String usr;
@Value("target.key")
String key;

@Bean
public TargetConnector connector() {
  return new TargetConnector(url, usr, key);
}
```

Now when I use the connector jar in the client I can find the configuration via packagescan. The connector class is loaded but the problem is that it does not load the properties files.

**Research**

I found that multiple property files cannot have the same name (e.g. clients application-{profile}.properties clashes with the one from the connector), so I tried to rename **application-{profile}.properties** of the targetConnector to **application-connector-{profile}.properties**.
The properties whoever still do not get loaded, (which makes sense since I do not have a e.g **connector-dev** profile but my profile is simply named **dev**).

Furthermore, even if I try to explicitly load one of the property files from the connector with:

```
@PropertySource({"classpath*:application-connector-dev.properties"})
```

it cannot be found

**Question**

My question is actually 3 tiered:

1. How can I load a property file in a dependency jar at all?
2. How can I load the profiled version of the property file if the the properties file has a different name than application.properties? e.g. application-connector.properties
3. How can i combine the answers from question 1 and 2 to load the profiled version of the property in the jar?

If further explanation is needed, please ask.

**Answer**

I went for an approach as given in the accepted answer. 
I Just created 3 configs for the dev, tst, prd profiles containing the values needed and annotated the config files with the correct profiles.

Comment: In your example of explicit loading, have you tried removing the `*` after `classpath`, ie `@PropertySource({"classpath:application-connector-dev.properties"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using @Configuration annotated class. Maybe you can have one per profile. Here you are an example:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("profileA")
@PropertySource({"classpath:application-profileA.properties"})
public class ConfigurationProfileA{
 @Value("${target.url}")
 String url;
 @Value("${target.usr}")
 String usr;
 @Value("${target.key}")
 String key;

 @Bean
 public TargetConnector connector() {
   return new TargetConnector(url, usr, key);
 }
}
```

Do the same for profile B (maybe you can structure this better but the key points here are the annotation @Profile("") and @PropertySource(""))

Once you have your config class, Spring will use the Configuration class you want by just filling -spring.profiles.active=profileA (or the name of the profile you have written in the @Profile("") annotation)

Comment: I used your approach with a config just containing a simple class containing the values needed and creating a bean from it, now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in this line @PropertySource({"classpath*:application-connector-dev.properties"}) 
Please check by removing the asterik.

Comment: with removing the star, spring found the file, thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

In order to run with a specific profile, you can run with option `-spring.profiles.active=dev` for example

If you don’t run with a profile, it will load the default profile in `application.properties` that you don’t seem to have.

Furthermore, an advice would be to always have an application.properties and put in it the common properties and the default values that you would override in other properties files.

Other mistake is how you assign properties with `@Value` annotation, you need to use `@Value("${PROPERTY_FROM_PROPERTIES_FILE}")`